# Link one item with another line

Tags: eclipse, system-verilog

I want to put all my comments/documentation about the file's contents at the end of it and create something like references/tags that point to a part of the code.

THE FOLLOWING IS JUST A THOUGHT/EXAMPLE:

I'm think that something like `//[reference_X]` would work (pseudocode):

```
module counter (clk,rst,enable,count);
input clk, rst, enable;
output [3:0] count; //[count]
reg [3:0] count;

always @ (posedge clk or posedge rst)
if (rst) begin
  count <= 0;
end else begin : COUNT
  while (enable) begin
    count <= count + 1;
    disable COUNT;
  end
end

endmodule
/**
* [count]: just an example, this register acts
* as something that explains what the asker is
* looking for.
*/
```

My main tool is Eclipse but I have DVT Eclipse on if that helps (can't find tag for it).

Target language is system-verilog.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? In a long file this means that the comments about a piece of code would be very far away from the actual code leading to a lot of up/down scrolling.

Comment: @Tudor From what I've seen/figured so far:Long comments/descriptions between HDL code lines make it harder to read in the long run.  Usually it's just very specific lines that need extensive explaining, the other lines are/become just trivial code after some point. (also DVT provides a "go back" extension - the "go to" is the thing in need)

Comment: IMHO I disagree with this, but to each his own. In any case, I don't think DVT parses any of the words inside the comments in any way (except to build docs) so the "go to" feature might not work in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with DVT 18.1.15 you can use hyperlinks in comments (https://dvteclipse.com/documentation/sv/Hyperlinks_in_Comments.html)

You just need to write **@link element** or **@see element** and DVT will go to the declaration of that element. To trigger this, simply hold the CTRL key while hovering the element name in the comment.

There are several ways you can specify an element to be referenced. If DVT cannot detect a unique element, it will suggest more hyperlinks.